# AMD catalyst driver 12.1 Kubuntu 12.10 (64 bit)

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, asus, catalyst

I have an ASUS N56DP laptop and I have Kubutu 12.10 working on it with the default graphics drivers. The system hangs if I use any of the additional drivers suggested by jockey-kde. I am thinking about installing the AMD catalyst 12.10 to get better graphics performance. 
The graphics card on my system is RADEON HD 7730 M.

Has anyone tried this out and want to share their experience?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Imho you should try to install Catalyst Driver on Kubuntu. It will enable 3D graphics acceleration.

Regards,
Over Killer

Comment: thanks, but do you know if the driver is stable for this hardware configuration and works for quantal.

Answer (score 0):

I've only just installed Kubuntu 12.10 (trying it out). I had the same "hang" problem after installing the AMD Catalyst 12.10 drivers. I'm going to try and install the AMD Catalyst 12.11 beta driver when I get home. If you Google around, there are many people experiencing problems with AMD's Catalyst 12.10 driver on Linux.

I'll report back here after I've performed the AMD Catalyst 12.11 beta install.

Comment: I bit the bullet and installed the driver. The installation went without any troubles; however after I restarted my computer, and started AMD catalyst control center, it just complains saying that no driver is installed !! Luckily my graphics drivers are still working ( I have no idea, which drivers are running the show).

Answer (score 0):

When you switch to the Catalyst driver you have to add "nomodeset" to your kernel boot flags to turn off Kernel Mode Setting. The catalyst driver doesn't work with KMS.

PS: I also have this N56DP. Suspend/Resume always crashes for me. Have you had any luck with it? Also, it always tries to suspend when you close the lid. I haven't found any way to disable that, the usual power manager settings have no effect.